# iOS Sprite Kit how to reflect a sprite horizontally?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, sprite-kit

Is there a way to create a SKSpriteNode and pass it an image name, but have it reflect the image horizontally?

Answer (score 4):

You mean you want to flip the image?

```
node.xScale = node.xScale * -1;
```

or

```
node.yScale = node.yScale * -1;
```

Comment: xScale flips the node and all of its children. This works for simple sprites, but if the sprite has children, I need to reflect the image only, not everything.

Comment: Separate the image from the node. Thus create a SKNode and append a SKSpriteNode with the image. Append the children to the SKNode.