# SpriteKit: xScale makes SKEmitterNode invisible

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scale, skemitternode

I have a SKSpriteNode with a child which is a SKEmitterNode.
When the SKSpriteNode touches the right end of the screen I mirror the SKSpriteNode:

```
bird.xScale = -1
```

My problem is, that a negative scaling factor makes the SKEmitterNode invisible.

Comment: I want to flip the node along the x axis.

Comment: Read a bottom comments on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008886/ios-sprite-kit-how-to-reflect-a-sprite-horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bird.xScale = bird.xScale * -1
```